# Browse directory and extract word from folder name

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I have the following list of folders having two words in name separate by a space

```
WEB TEH
COMPUTER SCIENCE
UNIX LINUX
```

I would create a shell script, this script can browse the directory and extract the first and the second word from each folder ,

and put each one of extracted word into a text file (each of word in one line)

file1.txt contain :

```
WEB
COMPUTER
UNIX
```

and file2.txt contain:

```
TECH
SCIENCE
LINUX
```

Thank You

EDIT:

I create this script :

```
#!/bin/bash

# Read folder name and put it in file
read -p "Enter Your Path: "  Path
for entry in $Path
do
   echo -e "$entry">>file.txt
done

#Browse file and echo line
file="/home/user/file.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
done 
<"$file"
```

but i cant' get the folder name (in this script i get the path)

and i don't know how to extract the two word

---

EDIT 2:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Read and put nom/prénom dans un fichier
read -p "Enter Your Path: "  Path
for entry in $Path
do
   word= basename $entry 
   echo -e "$word">>file.txt
   cat file.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 1 > file1.txt
   cat file.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 2 > file2.txt
done
#Browse folder 
file="/home/user/file.txt"
#while IFS= read -r line
#do
#       printf '%s\n' "$line"
#done <"$file"
```

the output of script is :

```
COMPUTER
UNIX
WEB
```

when i execute cat file1.txt , i don't see the content of fike

---

EDIT 3 :

I can show the name of folder

```
for entry in $path
do
 echo ${entry##*/}>>file.txt
done
```

but , how i can extract the two word ?

Comment: Please stop posting updates as answers. Put your updates [in your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/475375/edit).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls "$1" > file.txt
cat file.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 1 > file1.txt
cat file.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 2 > file2.txt
```

Save it somewhere and use `./script_name /home` or something like that.

Edit:
follow these steps

1. Create a file named `script` with the the above commands in the current directory.
2. Run `chmod a+x script`. (this makes your script executable)
3. Run `./script DIR_NAME`. (replace DIR_NAME with your desired directory)
4. This will create two files `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` in the same directory as of `script`

Comment: when i execute " cat file1.txt" , i dont' see the content of file

Comment: @YOUCHTLEE please elaborate a little more.

Comment: I'am noob with shell/sctipt

Comment: It should work fine! can you tell me exactly what you are doing?

Comment: @YOUCHTLEE I added the steps you should follow. for one thing, you don't need a while loop. do as I did. Besides, in your answer below, you are using `> file1.txt` that actually writes to a file as if it was empty. Use `>> file1.txt`

Comment: If my script was wrong , Please add a answer and correct them

Comment: Any helo please